# How do I efficiently control normalisation in a keyman keyboard using groups?

Tags: keyboard, keyman, keyman-developer

I am in the process of refactoring and redesigning the code in a few keyboards. The keyboards use options to control whether Unicode Normalisation Form C (NFC) or Normalisation Form D (NFD) is used.

An example of how I currently implement this is :

```
if(nfc = "1") + any(diaeresisKeys) > U+0308 use(nfc_processing)
if(nfc = "0") + any(diaeresisKeys) > U+0308 use(nfd_processing)
```

I will be adding support for marking tones, and this will multiply the number of rules requiring redirection to another group.

This there a more efficient mechanism for flow control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are doing it is good for single rules. If you have multiple places where you want to do normalisation, you may find it better to move the [`if()` statement](https://help.keyman.com/developer/language/reference/if) to a separate [context-only group](https://help.keyman.com/developer/language/guide/groups), for example:

```
+ any(diaeresisKey) > U+0308 use(normalise)

group(normalise)

if(nfc = "1") > use(nfc_group)
if(nfc = "0") > use(nfd_group)
```

That means that you are doing the test in only one place, halving the number of rules.

To simplify even further, you can use the [`match` rule](https://help.keyman.com/developer/language/reference/match) which is processed once after any rule in its group is matched. This [DRYs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) out the `use` statements:

```
+ any(diaeresisKey) > U+0308

match > use(normalise) 

group(normalise)

if(nfc = "1") > use(nfc_group)
if(nfc = "0") > use(nfd_group)
```

Comment: In the el_dinka layout I have oped to use the first option.

I am only passing off to the normalise group when normalisation is an issue, other rules are processed in the main group.

So `match > use(main)`  at end of the constraints group.